# ip address of user using java

Tags: java, ip-address

Like to get the IP address and some other details for a web application.
eg: location, language, country etc of the user using java.

I found one tool from sourceforge. Don't know whether it's good. 
[java IP Locator](http://javainetlocator.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: User of what? A website?

Comment: yes for a web appliation. edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you try the [GeoIP Java API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/java) by MaxMind. It is also used by [Shareaza](http://www.shareaza.com/) for torrent purposes.

Answer (score 4):

If this is for a web application, try using  `ServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()`.

As for the location of the ip address, we're using [Maxmind's GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry).

The browser language might be read from the request header.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that the IP address may be the IP of a proxy server, not the machine where the requests are ultimately coming from.